# Method Created Objects Deleted on Exit

Tags: java, memory, methods

Are objects / fields created in a method deleted upon the exit of that specific method?

Example:

```
public static void createFolder() {

    File folder = new File(C:\example\path "foldername");
    folder.mkdir();
}
```

Would the MEMORY used to store the File "folder" be deleted upon exit of the "createFolder" method?

Comment: Is this purely academic or is there a deeper question?

Comment: @KarthikT I'm trying to find the best way to check for folder existence & create one if needed (can't write to files if the folders aren't there). My post shows a dumbed-down version I'm currently using. TL;DR: Academic.

Comment: @Aaron When you say `folder` are you talking about the local var or the actual File system folder? I expect the actual folder would not get deleted if your `folder` var is garbage collected.

Comment: @KarthikT "folder" is being referred to as an example, similar to "C:\example\path. It does not exist outside of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `File` object referred to by `folder` becomes eligible for garbage collection upon exit from the method since the only reference to it (`folder`) goes out of scope at that point.

When it is actually garbage collected is impossible to tell exactly, but it will be sometime after that point.

More generally, local variables in a method are allocated on the stack and are deleted when they go out of scope.  If they are primitives (int, float, long, etc) they cease to exist immediately. If they are references (as in your case) the reference ceases to exist immediately but the object referred to continues to exist as long as a reference exists. For example, if your `createFolder()` method were to return the value of `folder`, and the caller preserved that reference in one of its own variables, then the `File` object would not be (yet) eligible for GC.  When *all* references to an object cease to exist then the object itself is eligible for GC.  The language does not specify exactly when GC occurs.

This is complicated a little by some esoteric topics having to do with "weak" references but you can ignore those for the time being.